# SQLite exception with RSpec, Spork and Database Cleaner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sqlite, spork

Works great for about 5 runs, but then all tests fail with:

```
ArgumentError: prepare called on a closed database:           SELECT name
             FROM sqlite_master
             WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
```

Doesn't happen without Spork, and works fine if I restart Spork. Doesn't happen after a certain number of runs, but changes each time.

Any ideas what could cause this?

EDIT:

It only happens when changing the controller code.

spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'spork'
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start

Spork.prefork do
  ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

  require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
end

Spork.each_run do # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'capybara/rails'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    config.include RequestHelpers, :type => :request

    config.before :suite do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
    end

    config.before :each do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after :each do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.include(MailerHelpers)
    config.before(:each) { reset_email }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing this line:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Seems to have worked for me. I was guided by the error message, as it was transaction related, but not exactly sure what the deal is. Seems to have something to do with spork's threads and sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

I had this error quite a bit and was able to fix it by updating to the latest version of sqlite3.

```
bundle update sqlite3
```